# Complete list of special Java comment tags

Tags: java, comments

I just found out I can write "{@value}" in the comment of a public static final field to insert the actual field value into the comment. Example:

```
/** The value of this field is {@value}. */
public static final int someField = 3
```

In Eclipse, this comment is displayed as "The value of this field is 3".
Another trick is to write "{@code some-code}" in order to insert code into a comment.

Is there a complete list of these special comment tags somewhere? I couldn't find one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should get you started:

- [javadoc - The Java API Documentation Generator: Javadoc tags](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags)

Note the [`-tag`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#tag) option though.  Tags are extensible, so there's no such thing as a *complete* list.

Comment: I appreciate the help. However, the {@value} and {@code ...} tags seem to be "built-in", without being mentioned in the official documentation. So I'm looking for a list of these inofficial built-in comment tags.

Comment: @python: They're in the second link.  They were just added later.  I'm going to remove the first link since it's out of date and as far as I can tell doesn't tell you anything more than the second.

Comment: I was in fact refering to all your links, including the "Custom tags and Annotations" link. I don't know if the {@value} and {@code} tags were set up using Java's custom tags facility, but I know they're built into plain vanilla Eclipse. That means there should be a list of these tags somewhere.

Comment: @python: Once again, they **are** documented in (now) the first link of my answer.  You're not looking hard enough, or you're miles behind my edits  :-).

Comment: Okay, I finally caught up with your edits :-)

Answer (score 1):

For Java 12: [Documentation Comment Specification for the Standard Doclet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html)